# touchscreen keypad

Tags: android

I am developing an application for Android.

I need to display a numeric keypad on the screen.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this myself. I've not been able to present and entirely numeric only keypad, but you get closest with this combination:

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/someid"
  android:inputType="phone"
  android:numeric="integer"
</EditText>
```

The `inputType="phone"` changes the keypad from the normal keypad to one with fewer, bigger buttons (whereas `inputType="numberDecimal"` uses the normal keypad, but starting on the number keyset) and the `numeric="integer"` means anything except numbers are ignored (i.e. they don't even appear in the EditText). There's also a `numeric="decimal"` if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

What needs the numeric input?  If it's an EditText, main.xml should have an entry like

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/someid"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal">
</EditText>
```

This would show the number pad when the user taps the input field.